# Reallocing nested array of structs in another struct in function

Tags: c, function, struct, memory-management, realloc

I'm trying to store table(stored in a file) into memory. I have here my edited code for simplicity. Im running into segmentation fault so I think it has to do something with that I try to store values without declaring the arrays actually. But I read it shouldn't be a problem as struct arrays are dynamic on their own? I don't really know. So in function addcelltoTable I tried some reallocating, but unsuccessfully. Can you help me understand memory allocating and maybe pointers a little more?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <errno.h>
typedef struct Cells
{
    bool selected;
    char *Content;
} cell;

typedef struct Rows
{
    int someint;
    cell cells[];
} row;
typedef struct Tables
{
    int NumberOfColumns;
    int NumberOfRows;
    row rows[];

} table;
void addCellToTable(table *dataTable, char *cellContent, int row, int column)
{
    if (row > dataTable->NumberOfRows)
    {
        dataTable->NumberOfRows = row;
    }
    if (column > dataTable->NumberOfColumns)
    {
        dataTable->NumberOfColumns = column;
    }
    *dataTable->rows[row].cells = (cell*)realloc(dataTable->rows[row].cells, column*sizeof(char*)+1);  //here I'm trying to realloc array of cells , error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘cell’ {aka ‘struct Cells’} from type ‘cell *’ {aka ‘struct Cells *’}
    //*dataTable->rows = (row*)realloc(dataTable->rows, (sizeof(dataTable->rows)*sizeof(char*))); //realloc array of rows ?
    *dataTable->rows[row].cells[column].Content = *cellContent;
    printf("%d : %d : %lu : %s\n", row, column, strlen(dataTable->rows[row].cells[column].Content), dataTable->rows[row].cells[column].Content);
}
int main()
{
    char numberitoa[10];
    table dataTable;
    /*dataTable.NumberOfColumns=0;
    dataTable.NumberOfRows=0;
    dataTable.rows[0].someint=0;
    dataTable.rows[0].cells[0].selected=false;
    dataTable.rows[0].cells[0].Content="";*/
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        {
            sprintf(numberitoa, "%d", rand());
            addCellToTable(&dataTable, numberitoa, i, j);
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < dataTable.NumberOfColumns + 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < dataTable.NumberOfRows + 1; j++)
        {
            printf("main: %d, %d, %s\n", i, j, dataTable.rows[i].cells[j].Content);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The structs can contain arrays but you have defined them as cells[] rows[] etc. inside your structs. Behaviour will be a bit standard dependent but you haven't actually allocated any memory to them. Either provide an array size in the typedef or initialise the array elements using calloc().

Comment: Are you allocating memory to Content before writing to it?

Comment: Change `cell cells[];` to `cell *cells;` and similar for `rows`. Don't you get compiler warnings?

Comment: @KamilCuk no, no errors or warnings regarding structs. Why should changing to *cells make sense ? i need to store multiple cells not one. or I can make that pointer point to array ?

Comment: @ryyker that's what I'm trying to do but I don't really know how.

Comment: @JonGuiton I'm running on c99 I believe that's what you mean. I'm looking at some calloc documentation, I didn't knew you could for example make a pointer to int and then somehow access more ints with index. I'm quite confused by it actually. Also, calloc will erase data I have in that table every time I add a new cell no?

Comment: `or I can make that pointer point to array ?` That's exactly what generally pointers are for... And `call calls[]` is a _flexible struct member_ in that context and you do not anywhere allocate memory for it.

Comment: OT: regarding: `*dataTable->rows[row].cells = (cell*)realloc(dataTable->rows[row].cells, column*sizeof(char*)+1);`  1) in C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code (and is error prone)  Suggest removing the cast.  2) The function; `realloc()` can fail.  Therefore, do not directly assign the returned value to the target pointer, rather assign it to a 'temp' pointer, check the temp for NULL, if NULL then handle the error.  Otherwise, assign the 'temp' pointer to the target pointer

Answer (score 1):

An array declared with [] at the end of a structure is a flexible structure array, not a pointer to an array. Consequently you cannot reallocate it (instead you should reallocate the whole structure). Therefore it seems simpler to use a pointer to the allocated memory. This slightly changes the structures :

```
typedef struct Cell
{
    // You cannot use the same storage for each string as you did
    // instead we can use a fixed sized string (no allocation required)
    char Content[10]; 
    bool selected;

} cell;

typedef struct Rows
{
    int someint;
    cell * cells;
} row;
typedef struct Tables
{
    int NumberOfColumns;
    int NumberOfRows;
    row * rows;

} table;
```

There was a subtle issue in your allocation codes : when you allocate a row, the `rows->cells` array contains garbage, which makes any function called on it (including realloc) subject to crash. So these arrays must be set to NULL immediately after the rows have been allocated.

```
void addCellToTable(table *dataTable, char * cellContent, int row, int column)
{ 
    if (dataTable->NumberOfRows != row + 1) {
        dataTable->rows = realloc(dataTable->rows, (row + 1) * sizeof(struct Rows));
        for (int i=0; i <= row; i++) dataTable->rows[i].cells = NULL; //<== here
    }
    if (dataTable->NumberOfColumns != column + 1)
        dataTable->rows[row].cells = realloc(dataTable->rows[row].cells, (column + 1) * sizeof(struct Cell));
    
    // The fixed sized string must be set with memcpy
    memcpy(dataTable->rows[row].cells[column].Content, cellContent, strlen(cellContent) + 1);
    
    dataTable->NumberOfRows = row + 1;
    dataTable->NumberOfColumns = column + 1;
}
```

Finally your arrays are reallocated at each iteration so the print statement should be in the same loop than the allocations otherwise you cannot print all allocated cells.

```
int main()
{
    char numberitoa[10];
    table dataTable = {0};
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {
            sprintf(numberitoa, "%d", rand() % 1000);
            addCellToTable(&dataTable, numberitoa, i, j);

            printf("main: %d, %d, %s\n", i, j, dataTable.rows[i].cells[j].Content);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```